# Opencv extract laser line

Tags: python, opencv

I need help using Python to extract a red laser line on an object from an image. I want to use the shape of the line to determine if the object is flat or tapered, and if it's tapered, on which side.

[image]

Comment: Could you post sample images, and the code you have so far?

Comment: hello i added the image, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting this RGB image to the HSV scale and then using the known range of the color of the laser line, filter everything else out.

Once you do this, you can clean up the image using [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) like cv2.erode().

Once you do this, you can use line detection using either HoughLines or the [line segment detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#linesegmentdetector-detect). You should be able to figure out the angle of each line segment from this.

This general technique should be a good starting point for you. Once you start encountering problems, you can ask more specific questions and we should be able to help with that.

Warning: You will likely have a lot of noise in this image that you will have to manage.